# Listing all the properties in a Kotlin class excluding the ones with custom getters

Tags: kotlin, reflection, kotlin-reflect

Is there a simple method I can use to list all of the properties in a class that don't implement a custom getter?

###### For example:

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) {

    val signature: String get() = "$name - $age"
    
    val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
}
```

Using the code above, I would like to find the following:

###### `[ Person::name, Person::age, Person::uuid ]`.

Comment: By looking into the generated bytecode I think there is nothing really there to distinguish a generated and custom getter. Fortunately, Kotlin compiler attaches metadata to the generated bytecode and it is quite probable such information is there. Metadata is binary, so I didn't check it by myself, but you can read it with: [kotlinx-metadata](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/kotlinx-metadata/jvm/ReadMe.md) lib. In the source code I see flags like: `IS_SYNTHESIZED`, `IS_DECLARATION` for functions, `HAS_GETTER` for props, etc., so maybe one of them will be helpful.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  I can't help wondering if there's a better approach without using reflection.  (Reflection is an advanced tool, but it's slow, fragile, insecure, ugly, and prevents many compile-time checks.  It's needed for specialised situations such as frameworks, plug-ins, and annotation processors, but IME it's very rarely appropriate in general application code, and so is a bit of a code smell.  Some of the patterns common in scripting and other dynamic languages don't translate well to static languages such as Java and Kotlin, where there are usually better designs.)

Comment: @gidds It's quite difficult to explain exactly why I need this. I have a very narrow use case for it in unit tests. I wrote some [custom equality checking utility](https://github.com/bright/kequality) that is very helpful in some situations to avoid a lot of boilerplate code when comparing large classes with a lot of properties. I would like to filter out the properties with custom getters.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will return a list of all class properties with a backing fields and exclude all artificial properties.

```
Person::class.memberProperties.filter { it.javaField != null }
```

Answer (score -1):

Properties that only have a getter do not have a JVM backing field, therefore; you can take all the properties, and exclude the ones that do not have a field.

```
// All properties
Person::class.declaredMemberProperties.forEach {
    println(it.name)
}
println()

// All fields
Person::class.java.declaredFields.forEach {
    println(it.name)
}
println()
```

*It should be noted that the `signature` is missing from the second set.*